# Complete Glassfish Guide with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I want to start a JavaEE project, I've read about where to start with JavaEE and most of them were directed to Glassfish. I installed it, and was able to get to the localhost, however I don't know where to go next. Is there a complete guide or tutorial on how to use Glassfish? Also if I can use MySQL with Glassfish for the JavaEE project.

Comment: Glassfish has fantastic code samples across dozens of topics baked in. Or maybe i downloaded them off their dev support page from Sun. Rollup your sleeves and have fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use MySQL. You can find a complete guide for setting up a connection with MySQL for Glassfish [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html).

An IDE like Netbeans is probably the easiest way to get started with JavaEE. You only need to add your freshly installed Glassfish server to Servers (under Services tab), then you can start working on your project.

However, it may be advisable *not to* use IDE at the beginning, since it hides from you some essential operations. Therefore, you'd better start by making your first 'test' project manually (I mean building and deploying).
There are several books for beginners to JavaEE platform and they usually start with a decent introduction on how to accomplish that. For example this one covers the topic in details:
Beginning Database-Driven Application Development in Java EE by Yuli Vasiliev.

Comment: Thanks mmalik, I'll look into the book.